# Index Page Showed on All Pages In Directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, expressionengine

We are using a CMS called ExpressionEngine.

We have template/folder called Contact - that has and index file. We only have the index page for contact because we have no deeper URLs that we need for Contact.

However if you add anything to the end of the normal contact pages URL it loads the same content at the contact page but isn't redirects and keeps the random URL.

Example:

This is the correct URL and displays the index content:

http://www.example.com/contact/

These are incorrect URLs (that still work - everything works) and it displays the index content:

http://www.example.com/contact/kjhfd/ 
http://www.example.com/contact/kjhfd/kljhdf/ 
http://www.example.com/contact/f/

We want that to stop and 301 redirect to http://www.example.com/contact/.

I have tried RedirectMatch with htaccess - I've tried 301 Redirect in htaccess and I've tried a funky PHP if redirect - none of which have worked so far

We have no PHP redirects. We have many htaccess redirects, please see below:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Trailing backslash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have tried RedirectMatch with htaccess - I've tried 301 Redirect in htaccess and I've tried a funky php if redirect - none of which have worked so far

Comment: good to know. You should update the question with explanations of what you've tried and how it's failed so we can help you troubleshoot the issues, rather than us simply writing possible solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy fix is to check for the segment_3 in the URL,if it exist then redirect to contact index page.You can use {redirect} tag.

```
{if segment_3}
 {redirect ="/contact"}
{/if}
```

Comment: valid response if we had no URLs with a 3rd segment but we do. This would also only address URLs that follow the /contact segment_2 - but it happens to almost all our templates so /product/location/ would also have the same issue where this (/product/location/foo) would be consider a real URL even though it isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following handler in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch ^/contact/.+$ /contact
```

This will  redirect a url with trailing path(s) to the correct location

```
/contact/foo
```

to

```
/contact
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but it redirects to /contact/?/contact/foo/

Comment: @trent Do you have any other php or htaccess redirects?

Comment: I have added most of our htaccess file above however I left out some unrelated 301 redirects as they identify the business